# Phonegap/Cordova Emulator - .apk Issue

Tags: android, cordova, apk, emulation

I have been following the tutorial here:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

It has worked for their "Hello World" app, but how would I do it for my own app?
I have tried putting my app code into the ProjectName/www folder, but when I do "cordova emulate android" on the CLI, it loads the .apk for the "Hello World" app instead of the one for my app.

Also, which files would I need to edit to make this happen?
For example, the build.xml or the config.xml files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you build your code? You need to build your code before you run it. `cordova build android` and then `cordova emulate android` Or you can run only one line to both build and run `cordova run android`

Comment: Yes, I did. But it chose the default "Hello World" .apk over my app's .apk.